# Spring однотипный код в контроллерах

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Вопрос следующий:
Необходимо написать веб приложение для работы со множеством справочников. 
Использую spring mvc + hibernate. Для каждого справочника необходимо написать код для выполнения crud операций. Т.к. планируется работа с сотнями справочников, то придется писать море однотипного кода в контроллерах. Вопрос в том, как можно решить данную проблему? чтобы был один контроллер, который бы работал с любым справочником.

Comment: Один из вариантов создать "абстрактный" контроллер, и потом создавать контроллер для каждого справочника наследуемый от абстрактного с нужными Вам методами.

Comment: Ну так и сделайте один контроллер для работы с любым справочником. IoC ?

Answer (score 1):

Без кода сложно что-то подсказать, но я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону использования дженериков в контроллере (вроде, `ProductController<Foo>`,`ProductController<Bar>`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Передавайте тип справочника в запросе. Затем, с помощью, например, паттерна 'Factory', можно получать нужный репозиторий.